# Using Pragma header on HTTP 1.1

Tags: http-headers

would like know your opinion about using

Pragma header 
when script is called in HTTP version 1.1

I don't know is good to return
both Pragma and Cache-Control

or rather return only Cache-Control

and at HTTP 1.0 return only Pragma ???

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Details around your use-case will be helpful in understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to deal with caching in HTTP1.1 is with the Cache-Control header. I cannot remember the last time I included Pragma in a HTML header.

[Cache Control for HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sect=14.9)

Answer (score 0):

Using both is fine. That way if you encounter a client that is using http 1.0 they'll be sure to honor your cache control request. Http 1.1 clients will simply ignore the redundant header so it won't cause any problems. I use both on lots of sites with no ill effects.